# How to echo multiple MAX values

Tags: php, arrays, max

```
     echo max([1, 7, 7, 3]);
```

I know the answer to that example is going to be 7. But as there are 2 highest values, I'd like the answer to be 7 & 7. Is there a way to ask for multiple highest values?

Comment: I don't see any arrays, I only see 4 different function calls. Please add more code an describe better where your problem is.

Comment: What is this? Pseudo-language?

Comment: The first code example is not valid PHP, @david.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rresult = array();
$result[] = $fish
$max = count($fish);
if (count($tomatoes) > $max){
  $result = array();
  $result[] = $tomatoes;
}
elseif (count($tomatoes) == $max){
  $result[] = $tomatoes;
}
if (count($banana) > $max){
  $result = array();
  $result[] = $banana;
  $max = count($banana);
}
elseif (count($banana) == $max){
  $result[] = $banana;
}
if (count($chicken) > $max){
  $result = array();
  $result[] = $chicken;
  $max = count($chicken);
}
elseif (count($chicken) == $max){
  $result[] = $chicken;
}
return($result);
```

Comment: I don't think this will generalise very well. What if the OP wants to add pomegranates and oranges?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to separately work out the max, and then see if you have more than one of them.

```
$array = [1, 7, 7, 3];
$max = max($array);

// This built-in function counts how many instances we have of each value
$counts = array_count_values($array);
if ($counts[$max] > 1)
{
    echo "There are " . $counts[$max] . " copies of the maximum value\n";
}
```

For more information, read up [on this function](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).